# Differential Privacy: understanding sensitivity

Tags: privacy, algorithm

From [this link on Differential Privacy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi5tbT4yKThAhUD4XMBHfq5CvcQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319620022-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1614771-p180940709&usg=AOvVaw3RqoeKqLz_v_yofpVp1TFO), the L-2 sensitivity is defined as follows:

[image]

**Question:**

Here's my understanding of the above equation:

- Make a set of `D'` data sets such that `D'` is same as `D` except it has an absence of a one row. For each `D'`, calculate the given L-2 norm and return the maximum L-2 norm.

In pseudo-code.

```
REQUIRE: D
INITIALIZE empty list: norms
FOR each row in D:
    1. Define D` such that D` is the same as D except it doesn't have "row" in it
    2. Calculate norm = ||f(D) - f(D')||_2 
    3. Store the norm in norms 
RETURN max value in norms
```

1. Is my understanding correct?

**Background:**

For a machine learning task, I'm trying to perform differentially private gradient descent optimization on a data set `D` by adding noise to the gradient.

In order to add Gaussian noise to the gradient, I need to calculate the L-2 sensitivity first. In my case, `f` is a vector-valued function (gradient), but I think there's no issue with the definition here.

[Related SO question on implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395148/implementing-l-2-sensitivity-maybe-using-numba-or-jax)

Comment: @ Rory Alsop I'm not sure the reason to mark this as off topic, my best guess is that you've seen this as a programming question - whereas this is not, this is asking about a specific definition in differential privacy. I hope specific questions on differential privacy are not off topic here; see: [what is differential privacy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49709/what-is-differential-privacy) and [Real-world applications of Differential Privacy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66531/real-world-applications-of-differential-privacy) are allowed although open ended.

Comment: The question you asked is not about privacy, though. It is either a pure programming question (how to implement the function in code) or a programming efficiency question (computationally feasible). The questions you linked are not open-ended even though they are conceptual.

Comment: @schroeder I want to ask "What is the definition of L-2 sensitivity?" I want to know what is written in that equation in plain English. I haven't intended this to be either a pure programming question or a computational feasibility question. I've written a pseudo-code because that conveys my understanding in an easy to understand way. I have added a plain English description to the top and removed the computational feasibility mentions, if that makes any difference.